# Translation of meromorphic function which is periodic w.r.t. to a lattice

Tags: complex-analysis, integer-lattices, meromorphic-functions

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, $\underline{u} \in \mathbb{C}^n\setminus \{ 0\}$, $\underline{v},\underline{w}\in \mathbb{C}^n$ and $L\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ a lattice of rank $2n$. Let furthermore $f: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a meromorphic function which is periodic with respect to the lattice $L$, i.e. for all $\underline{z}$ and all $\underline{y}\in L$ holds

$$ f(\underline{z}+ \underline{y})= f(\underline{z}).$$

Assume that in addition $f$ satisfies

$$ f(\underline{v} + x\underline{u})= f(\underline{w} + x\underline{u}) $$

for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ (where we fixed $\underline{u}, \underline{v}$ and $\underline{w}$ in the first line). Does this imply that $\underline{v}$ and $\underline{w}$ are equivalent modulo $L$?

Comment: did you mean for a given $u,v,w$  we have $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, f(\underline{v} + x\underline{u})= f(\underline{w} + x\underline{u})$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 That's what I mean. I fixed $\underline{u}, \underline{v}$ and $\underline{w}$ in the first line.

Comment: Then since $F(x) = f(v+xu)$ is complex analytic we have $\forall x \in \mathbb{C}, f(\underline{v} + x\underline{u})= f(\underline{w} + x\underline{u})$. But it doesn't mean $\forall \underline{u} \in \mathbb{C}^n, f(\underline{v} + \underline{u})= f(\underline{w} + \underline{u})$ (try with $n=2$ and some examples)

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @user1952009 could you think of a condition on $\underline{u}$ such that statement becomes true (e.g. entries of $\underline{u}$ $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$F(z_1,z_2) = f_1(z_1)f_2(z_2),  \qquad f_1(z) = \wp(z)\wp(2z),\qquad f_2(z) = \wp(z)$$

Then $F$ is $(1,0),(i,0),(0,1),(0,i)$ periodic and since $\wp(a)= \wp(-a)=0$ for some $a$ in the unit square we have
$$\forall z \in \mathbb{C}, \qquad F(-a/2,z)= F(a/2,z)=0$$
but $(a,0) \not \in \Lambda$.